# Delay to prevent multiple ajax calls on map dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm making an ajax call every time the map is zoomed or dragged as follows:

```
function initialize(lat, lng) {
   var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
   var mapOptions = {
      mapTypeControl: false,
      center: myLatlng,
      zoom: 15,
   };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
        getResults(map.getBounds());  
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
        getResults(map.getBounds());  
    });

};

function getListings(bounds){
 data = {'South_Lat':bounds.getSouthWest().lat(), 'South_Lng':bounds.getSouthWest().lng(), 'North_Lat':bounds.getNorthEast().lat(), 'North_Lng':bounds.getNorthEast().lng()};

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "<?=$results_url;?>",
    data: data,
    success: function (json) {
        // do something
    }
});
}
```

However, sometimes users may keep on dragging or zooming while one call is already being processed. One example is when the user uses the mouse wheel it triggers the zoom_change on every zoom step.

To prevent overloading the server, I would like to add a 1 or 2 seconds delay to wait for further zooms or drags before executing the ajax.

How can I implement this here?

Comment: if producing commercial apps using mapping api's do remember that google changes its licensing frequently and that it is currently not permitted to publish realtime tracking without paying a steep per user montlhy fee.  i recommend OSM (openstreetmaps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [underscore debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) (or an equivalent in another library) and the idle event.

```
var debouncedLoad = _.debounce(getDataFromServer, 2000/*2 seconds*/);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    debouncedLoad();
});
```

For jquery [there seems to be a plugin for this](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/)

Answer (score 0):

It was a reported bug
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1371.

Is recommend to use the event "idle".

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of that. Tried using the idle, but still doesn't solve my problem. Soon as I stop dragging or zooming it executes the ajax. Is there any way to increase the idle trigger time?

Comment: Stop to drag when ajax running, and unblock with ajax finish, its the only safe way to do that without idle event.

Comment: or, create a hublist for ajax call, and use jquery promisse, but this is more dificulty, much more.